# How do I make a Young tableau whose entries have subscripts?

Tags: packages, subscripts

I am using the youngtab package

I tried something like:

```
\young{{a_1}{a_2}{a_3},{b_1}}
```

but I cannot get it to work. I tried passing in `\textrm` but those are not recognized either.

The more general question is how to put any form of mathematical expression inside the boxes of a young tableau with the youngtab package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This package will do it: http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~mf/genyoungtabtikz.html You can follow the package documentation, and on the top of page 6 you will see how to use subscripts.

Comment: Thank you. I will test it out and accept if it works!

Comment: I saved the sty file, created a folder "texmf" whose location is /Users/<username>/Library/texmf, and called the package via \usepackage{genyoungtabtikz}, but it says that it cannot find the file "genyoungtabtikz.sty". Is there something obvious which I am doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe just put the style file for the moment in the same folder as your tex file. I can see that is not a long term solution, but at least you can test the package.

Comment: Ok great it works beautifully! (Thanks for that suggestion).

Answer (score 2):

You need two pairs of braces if the label does not consist of a single character:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{youngtab}

\begin{document}

\young({{a_1}}{{a_2}}{{a_3}},b)

\end{document}
```

[image]